# What is the best way to safely assign a unique ID number to each entity a user creates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logic, amazon-dynamodb

My users can create entries, each of which I want to automatically assign an ID number to. The entries are stored in a DynamoDB table and are created via lambda functions and api gateway.

The ID number must be unique and the process of assigning it must be robust and garuntee uniqueness.

My thinking now is to use a "global" variable that starts at 1 and every time an entry is created it assigns that entries ID to the global variables value, then increments the global variables value.

Would this approach work, and if so what would the best approach be to implement it? Can you think of a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will not scale.

Having a global variable will need you to be increment its value in concurrent safe manner(to avoid race conditions) and will also need persistence for the variable to support increments after application restarts.

To avoid this exact problem, one of the patterns used is to use UUID as your key. Dynamo DB's java sdk supports this pattern by providing a custom annotation `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey`. This ensures each entry has a random identifier generated for itself.

You should be able to get a library to generate UUID, if your preferred language in not Java.

Comment: What garuntees the ID generated by @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey will be unique? Is it just long enough that probability dictates the same one won't occur twice or does it have some built in mechanism to ensure this?

Comment: Yes, the chances of collision are minuscule cause of its size. No other mechanism. Most modern world distributed systems use the UUID at some place.

Comment: Thanks for the info.